# Single check box selection with jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

In jquery datatable, single check box should be selected.

This [link](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html) is working fine.

But above link is using **jquery.dataTables** `1.10.16` version. And I am using **jquery.dataTables** `1.9.4`.

Can the same functionality as listed in example given above be possible with **jquery.dataTables** `1.9.4` instead of **jquery.dataTables** `1.10.16`?

Comment: Why don't you just try it instead of asking here? For all I know, yes, this is possible

Comment: By replacing 1.10.16 to 1.9.4 , it is not working. Can u direct me to some link for jquery which is using jquery.datatables 1.9.4?

Comment: Can anybody direct me to link 'single check box selection using jquery.dataTables 1.9.4?

Comment: You **cannot** !! The selection extension is based on the 1.10.x API and there is no chance you can get it to work with 1.9.4, the fetures used is simply not supported.

Answer (score 2):

In the same page which you give the link, there are many explanation about to using "single check" oparetion.

At the end of the listed attachment, you can see the referanced .js file is

https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.5/js/dataTables.select.min.js

In your page, you should add this file referance after dataTable.js.

I think, the version of jquery is not important. The important file is "dataTables.select.js"!

Secondly, you must update your dataTable maker codes like the sample below;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        columnDefs: [ {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets:   0
        } ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child' // this line is the most importan!
        },
        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );
} );
```

### UPDATES :

Why dont you try to write your own selector function?

for example;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
            /// put your options here...
        } );

    $('#example').find("tr").click(function(){ CheckTheRow(this); });
} );

function CheckTheRow(tr){
    if($(tr).find("td:first").hasClass("selected")) return;

    // get the pagination row count
    var activePaginationSelected = $("#example_length").find("select").val();

    // show all rows
    $("#example_length").find("select").val(-1).trigger("change");

    // remove the previous selection mark
    $("#example").find("tr").each(function(i,a){
         $(a).find("td:first").removeClass("selected");
         $(a).find("td:first").html("");
     });

     // mark the picked row
     $(tr).find("td:first").addClass("selected");
     $(tr).find("td:first").html("<i class='fa fa-check'></i>");

     // re turn the pagination to first stuation
     $("#example_length").find("select")
                         .val(activePaginationSelected).trigger("change");

}
```

Comment: Just replacing 'jquery.dataTables 1.10.16' with  'jquery.dataTables 1.9.4' is not working. It is giving error 'TypeError: g.ext.selector is undefined (fileName - dataTables.select.min.js 1.2.5)', So jquery.dataTables version is important.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, legacy data table does not support or have that select extension.

Workaround:

1. Create checkbox element inside 'mRender' callback.
2. Bind action to the checkbox. (This can be done inside the fnRowCallback or outside as in my example in below fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Rohith_KP/dwcatt9n/1/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var userData = [
    ["1", "Email", "Full Name", "Member"],
    ["2", "Email", "Full Name", "Member"]
  ];

  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'data': userData,
    'columnDefs': [{
      'targets': 0,
      'className': 'dt-body-center',
      'mRender': function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
      }
    }],
    'order': [1, 'asc']
  });

  $('#example tr').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('row_selected'))
      $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
    else
      $(this).addClass('row_selected');
  });
});
```

Also, I suggest you to upgrade your datatable version. Then you can use that select extension.

Answer (score 2):

> Can the same functionality as listed in example given above be possible with jquery.dataTables 1.9.4 instead of jquery.dataTables 1.10.16?

**Yes.**

**But,** not using the [Select Extension](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html) since it requires at least version [1.10.7](https://github.com/DataTables/Select/issues/8#issuecomment-153774433).

For 1.9.4, a possible solution would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').find("td input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    selectRow(this);
  });

  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  function selectRow(clickedCheckBox) {
    var currentPage = table.fnPagingInfo().iPage;

    // Being unchecked
    if (!$(clickedCheckBox).is(':checked')) {
      $(clickedCheckBox).removeAttr('checked');
      getRow(clickedCheckBox).removeClass('selected');
      return;
    }

    var selectEntries = $("#example_length").find("select");
    var showEntriesCount = selectEntries.val();
    var totalRows = table.fnGetData().length;

    // If show entries != totalRows append total rows opiton that can be selected
    if (totalRows != showEntriesCount)
      selectEntries.append($('<option>', {
        value: totalRows,
        text: totalRows
      }));

    // Display all rows
    selectEntries.val(totalRows).trigger("change");

    // Removes all checked attribute from all the rows
    $("#example").find("td input[type='checkbox']").each(function(value, key) {
      getRow(key).removeClass('selected');
      $(key).removeAttr('checked');
    });

    // Check the clicked checkBox
    $(clickedCheckBox).prop('checked', true);
    getRow(clickedCheckBox).addClass('selected');

    // Re set the show entries count
    selectEntries.val(showEntriesCount).trigger("change");

    // If added, Remove the additional option added to Show Entries
    if (totalRows != showEntriesCount)
      selectEntries.find("[value='" + totalRows + "']").remove();

    // Go to the page on which the checkbox was clicked
    table.fnPageChange(currentPage);
  }

  function getRow(element) {
    return $(element).parent().parent();
  }
});
```

---

The above will require [fnPagingInfo](http://legacy.datatables.net/plug-ins/api) to take the user back to initial page. I haven't tested the solution on large dataset, tested it on a table with 150 rows, but should work fine on larger datasets too.

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tqoc7k88/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried below code and I checked and it is working fine, you need to update styles and scripts:
You havr to update the latest styles and scripts to achieve latest functionality.
[Single check box selection with jquery datatable](https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html)